# Tikz does not save colormap for scatter plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to save a scatter plot that I draw in python. This plot has x and y and uses concentration at each point as its color. the code is something like below: 
inteface = plt.plot(x_out,y_out,c=concentration)
tikz_save(interface.tex)

But I have realised the tikz only saves the x and y values. So when I try to load the .tex file in my document I only see a graph with one color. this is what I see: [image]

and this is what I want to have: [image]

I would really appreciate your help since this has been taking so much of my time and I havent figured out what the problem is yet!

Comment: Well, I know the code is in `python` so it would be useless in this case, but I suppose you have at least the data for the plot so we can test it?

Comment: @Alenanno I'm not sure the code would be useless. We certainly need at least one of the python code and the file that code produces.

Comment: If `matplotlib2tikz` generates the wrong code, I think you should post an issue at https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz But as it stands, we don't have enough information to find an answer, I think.